# PHP MySQL submitting dynamic fields, arrays in $_REQUEST

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I've got a form that has users fill out information for request. In a section of the form, I have an "Add More Phone" button that dynamically adds more text field and drowdown selections so users can add multiple types of phone numbers. Since the number of telephones that will be submitted is unknown, I am trying to figure out how to send all the data into the server so it can be inserted into the database.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-4">Tel:</label>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <input class="form-control required" name="phones[]" maxlength="14" type="text" placeholder="(888) 888-8888">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-4">Phone Type:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <select class="form-control" name="phonetypes[]">
                <option value="0"><b>Choose a phone type</option>
                <option value="1">Main</option>
                <option value="2">Fax</option>
                <option value="3">Mobile/Direct</option>
            </select>                       
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4"></label>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input onclick="addRow(this.form);" type="button" value="Add Another Phone" name="addphone" class="btn btn-info"></input>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The `addRow(this.form)` appends a new set of fields where you can enter more phone number and the phone types. This is where I'm not sure how the request is going to take the field values since we don't know how many phones will be added.

I have the request as:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action'])) {
$phones[] = $_REQUEST['phone'];
foreach($_REQUEST['phone'] as $phone) {
    $phone['phone'];
}
$phonetypes[] = $_REQUEST['phonetype'];
foreach($_REQUEST['phonetype'] as $phonetype) {
    $phone['phonetype'];
}
```

I definitely have no clue on where to go about this from here. Any help appreciated!

Comment: this is ok, just take a note that in your html the names are `...phones` and in your php they are `...phone`. Correct the `s` and it should work. `$_REQUEST['phones'] as $phone`, now `$phone` will hold the value of each posted phone, no need of `phone['phone']`

Comment: @RoyalBg you mean $phone['phonetypes'] instead?

Comment: It seems that you have the

Comment: @ilbesculpi What do I have?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish the comment. As Eugen said, your code seems fine. You should be getting two arrays: phones[] and phonetypes[], so, you must iterate those on your php script: foreach($_REQUEST['phones'] as $phone) ... foreach($_REQUEST['phonetypes'] as $phonetype)... you're missing the final 's'

Comment: @RoyalBg, after the foreach loop it's only giving me the latest phone and phonetype instead of the list?

Comment: @Noobtastic if you want a `list` look at `implode()` function. You have a collection of elements, the foreach is iterating over them, so each element is in the `value`. You can do whatever you want with it. E.g. if you want to insert into DB, inside the foreach you can do `INSERT INTO...` and each phone will be saved on separate row. But if you want all the phones in one line, you either need to concatenate inside the foreach or use `implode()`

Answer (score 0):

Every request parameter can only be sent once with a given name, if it is not an array. So you need to adapt your code to

- either use a different name for each phonetype and phone
- or use a name as `phonetype[]` to mark is as an array